# Finding which program has created a specific file

Tags: permissions, ownership

I'm making an application on my Ubuntu 16.04 pc, and I want to clean my home, because I installed and uninstalled lots of programs and now I have lots of files in my home that aren't mine but something that some program left behind. These files are hidden (`.filename`), but I don't want them there.

To finish, I know I can use the command

```
sudo ls -la
```

but it shows the group owner like this:

```
-rw-------  1 owner group    1194 Dez 21 10:53 XXXXXXXXXX.old
```

but what I really want to know is who created the file, who used it, what program... Because if the program which created the file isn't installed anymore, I want to delete that file.

How can I know which program created the file?

Comment: Give us some REAL LIFE examples of files in question. Are they all in ~/Desktop or ~/Home?

Comment: hello, @heynnema , cause have lots of folders in my home, actually, it's 
hidden, but it drives me crazy and I wanna delete them, but I just wanna delete who was creat by I program was deleted, but I can't know who is the owner a folder/document it's my problem... and yes they're in my home

Comment: Without real life examples, there's no way to help you. If you're looking at hidden folders in your ~/home... leave them alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if you run a program which creates a file, the file will be owned by your user. There is no way to know what program created it. For example, if I create two identical files with different programs:

```
$ bash -c "echo hello > file1"
$ sh -c "echo hello > file2"
```

There is nothing in the file attributes that distinguishes the files:

```
$ ls -l file1 file2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 6 Dec 21 11:47 file1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 6 Dec 21 11:47 file2
```

But you might find some clues:

- In the pathname, e.g. `~/.thunderbird/` or `~/.zshrc`
- In the file itself, e.g. `~/.zcompdump` contains shell arrays, and the `z` in the filename makes me think Zsh created it.

  The `file` utility might be useful for identifying filetype. (I can't think of a good example, but the usage is like `file ~/.zcompdump`, which prints `/home/user/.zcompdump: ASCII text`)